# Execution failed for task ':react-native-pjsip:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a react-native project cloned from github. [Here is the github project](https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip-app).

After `npm install`. I tried the `react-native run-android` and I got this:

```
/var/www/html/test/sipsip/react-native-pjsip-app/node_modules/react-native-pjsip/android/src/main/java/com/carusto/ReactNativePjSip/PjSipModulePackage.java:12: error: PjSipModulePackage is not abstract and does not override abstract method createJSModules() in ReactPackage
public class PjSipModulePackage implements ReactPackage {
       ^
/var/www/html/test/sipsip/react-native-pjsip-app/node_modules/react-native-pjsip/android/src/main/java/com/carusto/ReactNativePjSip/PjActions.java:307: error: cannot find symbol
                    value.put(mapKey, map.getArray(mapKey).toArrayList());
                                                          ^
  symbol:   method toArrayList()
  location: interface ReadableArray
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
:react-native-pjsip:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-pjsip:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 24.355 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I've tried many solutions but none of them solved my issue. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Additional info:
**react-native version:**

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.41.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem today, and was solved just updating my react-native in the project using

```
react-native-git-upgrade
```

If you don't have it installed yet (the upgrader), you can call

```
npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
```

Of course, there were some thousands of graddles to update, and .js files failing (Still working on it), but at least, I've passed the failure you described.

Answer (score 0):

Delete /ios and /android folders
Then run `react-native eject`